How can I attach sagging ceiling drywall to a truss?
I took down an interior wall. There are two trusses in each side of the wall. The ceiling drywall is attached to the truss on one side, but on the other side of the wall it is not. The distance from this truss to the now removed wall is 6 1/2”. It is sagging a bit and I don’t want insulation to be falling until we get it patched up.

Is there a typical drywall screw I should use to penetrate a truss? I just used a 1 1/4” long drywall screw and it barely went into the truss popped through the drywall.

The truss is running parallel to the exposed top plate at the 6 1/2” mark.
 The truss I am trying to attach to is the one in the right of the picture.

Are we seeing a 2x6 backer above the drywall in the second photo? Is that what you're trying to screw to?

@isherwood no that’s just 1 of the two boards that were above the wall. I am actually trying to screw in the truss

That confuses me even more. I assumed that the trusses were parallel to the removed wall. Maybe do some markup on your photos so I get it right.

You may as well start by moving all that insulation out of the way, you're not going to be able to make a reliable join with it there. this it may also give some glue as to why the screw was too short.

Why don't create a simple 1" deep box to enclose the open area between the the two ceilings?  Sort like if you were boxing in a beam.  That might be easier than trying to smooth out a difference in heights between the two rooms.

Let's clear up some faulty assumptions first.

Your drywall isn't sagging. It's simply out of alignment from one former room to the other. That's likely due to slight variation in ceiling joist level, or whatever. 5/8" drywall (what you likely have) is quite stiff and hasn't really moved since you took the wall down.

Drywall screws don't really work to move drywall. They merely fasten it. You'll need to use another means to move it, or you'll need a new plan.


That said, here's what I'd do. If I'm way off the mark, revise your post to add information.
Check for flex in the lower area. If it does flex without requiring a car jack to do so, press it up with a strut and a bit of lumber against the drywall (a simple T brace). Position this so you can screw past it. Press the drywall into position starting near one end, then run in a bunch of 1⅝" drywall screws to secure it. Don't put them so close to the edge of the drywall sheet that they blow out. Set them just barely below flush with the drywall surface. (There are collared driver bits available to help with this.) Keep them at least 2" apart so they don't completely disintegrate the sheet.
If there is no flex, you have a framing misalignment and your solution lies elsewhere. You'll need to either shim down the high plane to match the low one, or you'll need to do some heavy-duty skimming over a wide swath to taper the two together. To make this not look terrible in the morning light, it has to be at least 24-36" wide, and transition smoothly from each plane.

It does flex pretty easily. Just to clarify, do I want to put the brace at lowest point, and then start at one side of the room. Or brace where I start and slide it down as  I progress down the line?

I'm not sure I follow. Just brace somewhere to get the drywall up tight to the truss, then work from there.
